# sending data from python to flutter

Tags: python, api, flutter, nlp

I am working on developing a mobile application using flutter and I use the Python language as part of the project. I want to know how to send data between flutter and Python, especially sending data from Python to flutter.
For example if i have Python code like this :

> ```
> **thisdict** = {
>   "brand": "Ford",
>   "model": "Mustang",
>   "year": 1964
> }
> ```

i want to send the value of the dictionary **thisdict** to flutter How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the values stored in the dictionary are read from a database, which means you will hav to implement a RESTful-API on Python using Django's REST Framework or Flask's REST Framework.

[Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

[Flask-RESTful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This API will read values from the database upon a request and send the data back as a JSON object to the user/API Caller with the data required in the dictionary.

To send HTTP Post or GET Requests you will have to use Flutter-BLoC to send POST as well as GET Requests to an API and then capture the Response.

[Flutter BLoC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

Here's the documentation on FLutter BLoC.